# Stack Overflow question quality filter wants me to format formatted code

Tags: bug, quality-filter

I was making a pretty big post on Stack Overflow. I spoke of multiple ways to approach the problem at hand and some of my solutions. Therefore, it involved lots of code. It looks like this (sorry for a bit blurry pictures):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Yet, here is what I get:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Truth be told, I cannot see anything to trigger something like that. I may be wrong.

How can I get my question posted? Also, how can I improve my formatting?

P. S.: if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, this happens:
[image]

---

**Edit:** Huge thanks to [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte) for their comment. Turns out, the problem was triggered by missing blank lines in between code and text.

As I have written in the comments, I am keeping the post up as I still reckon this to be a bug.

Comment: I've had this when there's not a blank line between text and a code block.

Comment: @Scratte thank you very much! It helped. I will still keep the post up as it still seems to be a bug.